# How to make my MySQL SUM() query more faster

Tags: mysql, sql

I have about 1 million rows on `users` table and have columns `A AA B BB C CC D DD E EE F FF` by example to count `int` values `0` & `1`

```
SELECT 
CityCode,SUM(A),SUM(B),SUM(C),SUM(D),SUM(E),SUM(F),SUM(AA),SUM(BB),SUM(CC),SUM(DD),SUM(EE),SUM(FF)
FROM users 
GROUP BY CityCode
```

Result `8 rows in set (24.49 sec)`.

How to make my statement more faster?

Comment: I think it's as fast as it's going to get - I can't see anything in your simple query that could be causing the slowness. If you have `text` fields and they are large, consider putting them in a different table to reduce the row size and therefore the I/O load of the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) to to know the excution plan of your query.

Create atleast one or more Index. If possible make CityCode primary key.

Try this one

```
SELECT CityCode,SUM(A),SUM(B),SUM(C),SUM(D), SUM(E),SUM(F),SUM(AA),SUM(BB),SUM(CC),SUM(DD),SUM(EE),SUM(FF)
FROM users 
GROUP BY CityCode,A,B,C,D,E,F,AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF
```

Comment: Welcome, so how much time query is taking now? mysql version?

Comment: with some Index `(15.81 sec)` & I tested on another server it took `(4.32 sec)`. Hardware is related thing too.

Comment: ok. If you are using InnoDB engine, I strongly recommend to try with mysql 5.5. If you are not using InnoDB, I like to know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Create an index on the `CityCode` column.

Comment: This could help, cause of the group by.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is not because of SUM(), try to say `select CityCode from users group by CityCode;` it should take neary the same time...

Comment: This was a good thing to try. SUM wasn't at fault, it was other parts of the query that was slow.

Answer (score 1):

- Use better hardware
- increase caching size - if you use InnoDB engine, then increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value
- refactor your query to limit the number of users (if business logic permits that, of course)

Answer (score 0):

You have no WHERE clause, which means the query has to scan the whole table. This will make it slow on a large table.

You should consider how often you need to do this and what the impact of it being slow is. Some suggestions are:

- Don't change anything - if it doesn't really matter
- Have a table which contains the same data as "users", but without any other columns that you aren't interested in querying. It will still be slow, but not *as* slow, especially if there are bigger ones
- (InnoDB) use CityCode as the first part of the primary key for table "users", that way it can do a PK scan and avoid any sorting (may still be too slow)
- Create and maintain some kind of summary table, but you'll need to update it each time a user changes (or tolerate stale data)

But be sure that this optimisation is absolutely necessary.